# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings' пытаюсь сделать страницу голосований после долгого прерыва

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'
```

кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?
могу отправить любой файл

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, структуру папок/файлов проекта и файлик `manage.py`.

Comment: извините проблема ужн решена